# Upload an image file via rich text editor webpart of sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

My goal is to
Upload an image file via rich text editor webpart of sharepoint 2010
According to how seems can only to give URL of the image and not to upload a image 
Directly through the webpart

Answer (score 0):

Click in the rich text field and go to the insert sub-menu on the ribbon.  From there, if you have permissions, you can probably upload a file to the pages or images library.